# Linked List of Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two functions I'm looking to join together and I'm struggling with it. The first function lists all of the tabs I have in the sheet (on the actual doc I'm working on this is just over 100 tabs and growing).

```
function listsheets() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out 
}
```

The second function links cells based on there text; i.e., if there is a "data" cell, it would link to the "data" tab in my workbook.

```
function linkRange() {
  const startRow = 2, 
        column   = 1; 

  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
        sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("List of Sheets"),
        lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();


  for (let row = startRow; row <= lastRow; row++) {
    const range         = sheet.getRange(row, column),
          richTextValue = range.getRichTextValue(),
          targetSheet   = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(richTextValue.getText());

    if (targetSheet !== null) {
      const sheetId = targetSheet.getSheetId(),
            builder = richTextValue.copy().setLinkUrl(`#gid=${sheetId}`);

      range.setRichTextValue(builder.build());
    }
  }
}
```

What I am ultimately looking for is a way to automatically link this list of sheets, so the custom function would essentially read as "linkRange(listsheets())".

Comment: Could you provide some feedback on the provided solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if misunderstood your goal. From your code I suspect you need this:

```
function build_list_of_sheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var list = [];
 
  for (var sheet of sheets) {
    var value = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
      .setText(sheet.getName())
      .setLinkUrl('#gid=' + sheet.getSheetId())
      .build();
    list.push([value]);
  }

  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('List of Sheets');
  sh.getRange(2,1,list.length,1).setRichTextValues(list);
}
```

It takes the names all sheets and put them into column A of the sheet 'List of Sheets' as a list of links:

[image]

Comment: That is 99% of what I was going to do. I guess I could run a on edit trigger and it should update automatically. I was hoping for a function the way that my =listsheets() was working, that way I could move the starting cell around, where this will always place in the defined range. When I try to use this as a custom function it shoots this error message.

Error
Exception: You do not have permission to call setRichTextValues (line 15).

Comment: Custom function can not return formatted data, it can returns only raw values. As for the automatic update it can be done, but what the changes it should watch? Add/delete a new sheet? Rename a sheet? Do you really need that script do the checking and remake the list every time you type anything within your spreadsheet? It's a quite time consuming operation. I wouldn't recommend to fire it via `onEdit()` trigger. I'd recommend to use `onOpen()` and custom menu for this.

Comment: onOpen is a much better suggestion, thank you!